XCode 16 Swift Interoperability - Function type mismatch, declared as '@convention(thin)
I was using Swift CPP interoperability in XCode 15.
I used the code below to call and pass data from the CPP to the Swift side.
IN CPP:
class VideoPropertiesObserver {

public:

void (*updateOperationModeUI)(VideoCutterOperationMode) = nullptr;

void setOperationModeObserver(void (*fun)(VideoCutterOperationMode)) {
    updateOperationModeUI = fun;
}
    
};

IN SWIFT:
public class VideoCutterModuleManager{
public init(delegate : CppUpdateDelegate) {
    VideoCutterModuleManager.sharedInstance = self
    setObservers()
}
 private func setObservers() {
    
    manager.setupVideoPropertiesObserver();
    
    manager.videoPropertiesObserver.setOperationModeObserver(updateOperationModeUI)
}
private let updateOperationModeUI: @convention(c) (VideoCutterOperationMode) -> Void = { mode in
    VideoCutterModuleManager.sharedInstance?.delegate?.updateOperationModeUI(mode: mode)
}
}

But now after updating the Xcode to 16, now showing the below error -
Function type mismatch, declared as '@convention(thin) (__ObjC.std.__1.__wrap_iter<UnsafePointer<_>>, __ObjC.std.__1.__wrap_iter<UnsafePointer<_>>) -> Swift.Int' but used as '@convention(thin) (__ObjC.std.__1.__wrap_iter<UnsafePointer<_>>, __ObjC.std.__1.__wrap_iter<UnsafePointer<_>>) -> Swift.Int'

Multiple definitions of symbol '$sSo1soiySiSo3stdO3__1O0036___wrap_iterUnsafePointer__DgGIinaBdaV_AGtFTO'

